# How to upload file in casperjs without using fill related methods

Tags: casperjs

I have a file upload functionality which is not inside a form.

```
<input type="file" id="file_uploader">
```

How do I write casperjs script to test the upload?

Note:
I know about `fill` method in `casperjs` which can handle file upload inside a form. Also I know about `uploadFile` of `phantomjs`. Basically, I am looking for a provision that will handle file upload using API of casperjs without using fill related API methods.

Comment: If you know about the `page.uploadFile()` function, why don't you use it?

Comment: I don't want to tightly couple my test script to phantomjs!

Comment: The only other engine for CasperJS is SlimerJS and it implements the same API as PhantomJS. You're not really locked in to PhantomJS.